# Retrieve varbinary image from SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, mysqli

I've created a very simple PHP and SQL blog. I have the following fields in the datbase: post_title, post_content, post_category, post_date, post_image, user_name. The post_image field is VARBINARY(255). I can upload the file successfully in the database, but how do I retrieve it afterward and display it? Here is the code for displaying the blog. I would like to display the image above the h2 tag:

```
<?php
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)){
?>
<h2 class="post-title"><?php echo $column["post_title"]?></h2>
<div class="view-post-content"><?php echo $column["post_content"]?></div>
<p class="category">Category: <?php echo $column["post_category"]?></p>
<p>This post was written <?php echo $column["post_date"]?> by <?php echo $column["user_name"]?>.</p>
<a href="edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $column['post_id'] ?>">Edit</a> | <a href="delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $column['post_id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
<hr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

**1- Creating another php only to load the varbinary:**

For example load_img.php:

```
<?php

...
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
$sql = "SELECT post_mime, post_image FROM post WHERE post_id=" . $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query("$sql");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: " . $row["mime"]);
echo $row["img"];
}
mysql_close($conn);
```

Above your H2:

```
echo '<img src="load_img.php?id='.$column['post_id'].'" />';
```

**2- Or Using base64 css:**

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $column['post_image'] ).'"/>';
```

I would recomend a new field to store the **mimetype** (jpg, png, gif etc...)

Comment: The image still isn't displaying using your second method. Do I have to upload the image to a directory as well or can I just store it in the database?

Comment: @Julian you *can* just store it in the database- although it's MUCH more common to store it in the file system *instead*. If the images are small (under 100k) then either approach is fine,

Comment: @Julian the second method has a natural disadvantage because some browser have limits for base64 images. You can test images here: https://www.base64-image.de/